# Is it possible to store multiple groups and arrays in a single file?

Tags: zarr

I've been using HDF5 to store time series data and I want to try using Zarr due to its various features.

I'm reading its tutorial and following each step, and I've realized that maybe Zarr uses directories on a file system instead of a single file and hierarchical structures inside it?

For example, when I do this:

```
root = zarr.open('group.zarr', mode='w')
foo = root.create_group('foo')
bar = foo.create_group('bar')
z1 = bar.zeros('baz', shape=(10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000), dtype='i4')
```

I thought that a file named `group.zarr` would be created with 2 groups in the file. In reality, it creates 3 consecutive local directories.

I prefer saving arrays in a single file. Is it also possible to create multiple groups and arrays in a single file using Zarr, like HDF5 does?

Comment: Zarr arrays are generally stored in multiple files even if you're not creating groups. That's what it means when it says "chunked". It's something you see a lot with cloud-optimized file formats as opposed to older formats since it makes parallel access more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Zarr directories can be zipped together into a single Zip file:

```
7z a -tzip archive.zarr.zip archive.zarr/.
```

The [ZipStore](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html?highlight=zipstore#zarr.storage.ZipStore) can then be used to read the single files, though that should be transport for users from `zarr.open()`.